# Unable to access Tastekid’s API. It says Error: 403 (Request forbidden)

Tags: python, json, api

I am unable to run the code to read Tastekid's API (python), It says Error: 403 (Request forbidden) However i can access the same as a url in browser.
Have tried the same with the key aswell.

Please find below the query

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError
req = Request('http://www.tastekid.com/api/similar?q=red+hot+chili+peppers%2C+pulp+fiction')
try:
    response = urlopen(req)
except URLError as e:
    if hasattr(e, 'reason'):
        print 'We failed to reach a server.'
        print 'Reason: ', e.reason
    elif hasattr(e, 'code'):
        print 'The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.'
        print 'Error code: ', e.code
else:
    'everything is fine'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add proper [headers](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html#headers) before making the request to the url

```
headers = { 'User-Agent' : "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)" }    
req = Request('http://www.tastekid.com/api/similar?q=red+hot+chili+peppers%2C+pulp+fiction', headers = headers)
```

---

Here the `User-Agent` key within the headers is set so as to tell the server that we are making the request from a browser rather than a program

**Test**

- File name `test.py`

  ```
  from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError

  #Changes made in the below two line

  headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)' }
  req = Request('http://www.tastekid.com/api/similar?q=red+hot+chili+peppers%2C+pulp+fiction', headers = headers)


  try:
      response = urlopen(req)
  except URLError as e:
      if hasattr(e, 'reason'):
          print 'We failed to reach a server.'
          print 'Reason: ', e.reason
      elif hasattr(e, 'code'):
          print 'The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.'
          print 'Error code: ', e.code
  else:
      print 'everything is fine'
  ```
- Without headers

  ```
  $ python test.py 
  We failed to reach a server.
  Reason:  Forbidde
  ```
- With headers

  ```
  $ python test.py 
  everything is fine
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update. However if i have to make a request from a program rather than a browser then is there any other way?

Comment: The change I made is in the program only. will post the entire code for your reference

Comment: This is a good workaround to a problem on our end. You shouldn't have to pretend being a browser when making API calls. I just added a page rule in CloudFlare to disable the "Browser Integrity Check" for API URLs, so it shouldn't be necessary to do this anymore. (TasteKid founder here)